# Mariadb multi stage container with an existing database

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb

I need to create a container with an existing database and operate some actions on it before distribute it.
In production, I've got some really big databases:

```sh
[root]# ls /home/db-backup/test/prepare/26_06_2020/full/
ibdata1        
ib_logfile0    
ib_logfile1    
ibtmp1         
mysql
performance_schema
my_existing_database1
my_existing_database2
my_existing_database3
```

I just need to publish a container with `my_existing_database1` for my team.

I tried many Dockerfile but I can't find a way do to it and I don't understand why.
Here a simplified Dockerfile :

```
FROM mariadb:latest as builder

ENV MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD yes

# for easier debug, i will remove that in prod
RUN sed -i '/\[mysqld\]/a plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so' /etc/mysql/my.cnf

WORKDIR /initialized-db

COPY ibdata1 .
COPY mysql ./mysql
COPY performance_schema ./performance_schema
COPY my_existing_database1 ./my_existing_database1
COPY db-init.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/

RUN chown mysql:mysql . \
  && chmod 660 ibdata1 \
  && chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db-init.sh

RUN ["/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh", "mysqld", "--datadir", "/initialized-db", "--aria-log-dir-path", "/initialized-db"]

# No file named test
RUN ls /initialized-db/

FROM mariadb:latest
COPY --from=builder /initialized-db /var/lib/mysql
```

As you can see, I try to execute my script `db-init.sh`. Simplified version :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e -x

mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'test'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'test';"
touch /initialized-db/test
```

Unfortunetly, my script is not executed as the file `test` is not created.
I try to bypass the `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh` with my own script (copy/paste of the file with some edit) but it's not working either (user and file `test` not created).

Can you help me on this one please?

Comment: MariaDB and MySQL tables spaces aren't things to be copied/moved about. [follow the instructions on transportable tablespaces](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-file-per-table-tablespaces/#copying-transportable-tablespaces)

Comment: I don't think my question is relative to your link, the second container boot normally (and it's for dev not prod). I can read and write in it without problem. I just need to add an user on table mysql but I can't find a way.

Comment: You are selectively restoring parts of your file backups. This results in fragile instance and I wouldn't expect it to be reliable. There are references in ibdata1 to databases that aren't there. What output do you get building the docker container? If you at `set -x -v` to the entry point script do you see which bits are executed?

Comment: `mysql -u root -e 'CREATE USER '\''test'\''@'\''%'\'' IDENTIFIED BY '\''test'\'';'
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such fil$
error building image: error building stage: failed to execute command: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
fail`
Mysql does not seem to start in container 1 (ok in container 2). Do you know why ?
I can't work on it for now, but I will examine the trace later, thank you for the `-v`.

Comment: @Oyabi because Mariadb is launched in foreground by the CMD, your sql script will never-ever be run if it stands anywhere else than in an entrypoint, because your server is not launched.

Comment: Try FROM bitnami/mariadb:latest instead of FROM mariadb:latest

Answer (score 2):

You should preferably mount a directory for the data and distribute it then extra.

If you must distibute it with the container itself, you should be able to edit the config of that database to use a custom data directory and initialize your databases in it with `RUN` and `COPY`.